# Long argument to print() produces error "Expression was too complex to be solved"

Tags: swift, inheritance, compiler-errors, type-inference

I'm new with Swift and I have an issue when I want build this code. 
"Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions".

I think my method to manage attributed when I want print something is wrong but I didn't find why.

```
class Personne{
    var name : String
    var forename : String
    init(name : String, forename:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.forename = forename
    }
}

class UnilStudent : Personne{
    var id : Int
    var section : String
    init(name :String, forename:String, id:Int, section:String) {
        self.section = section
        self.id = id
        super.init(name:name, forename:forename)
}

    func affiche() {
        print("Unil student N°" + \(self.id) + " : " + \(self.name) + \(self.forename) + "\n" + \(self.section + "\n")}
}

class Assistants : UnilStudent{
    var assistantship : String
    init(name :String, forename:String, id:Int, section:String,  assistantship : String){
    self.assistantship = assistantship
    super.init(name :name, forename:forename, id:id, section:section )
}

    override func affiche() {
        super.affiche()
        print("Unil student N°" + \(self.id) + " : " + \(self.name) + " " + \(self.forename) + "\n from " + \(self.section) + "is a student assistant for" + \(self.assistantship) + "\n")}

    func printid(){
        print("L'id de " + \(self.name) + " " + \(self.forename) + " est "  +  \(self.id))

}
}


let Adrien = Assistants(name : "BOB", forename : "BOBBY", id : 12000000, section : "FDCA",  assistantship : "ACT")
let Alice = UnilStudent(name: "Hapoka", forename : "Alice", id : 17000000, section : "HEC")


print(Adrien)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to inheritance.
`\(...)` is for *string interpolation* and can only be used *inside* a string, for example:

```
print("Unil student N°\(self.id) : \(self.name)\(self.forename)")
```

instead of

```
print("Unil student N°" + \(self.id) + " : " + \(self.name) + \(self.forename))
```